# Undefined reference to MATLAB's matOpen in Fortran

Tags: matlab, fortran, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I get this error

```
/tmp/ifort2keEwa.o: In function `MAIN__':
/home/cg1116/carlos/VControl/Lyap_base.f:180: undefined reference to `matopen_'
/home/cg1116/carlos/VControl/Lyap_base.f:188: undefined reference to `matputvariable_'
/home/cg1116/carlos/VControl/Lyap_base.f:226: undefined reference to `matclose_'
```

when trying to export a matlab variable from fortran, using matOpen and matPutvariable. My code is the following

```
      integer matOpen,matClose
      integer matGetVariable,matPutVariable
      integer matPutVariableAsGlobal,matDeleteVariable
      integer mp,status

C     Open MAT-file for writing.
    write(6,*) 'Creating MAT-file matdemo.mat ...'
    mp = matOpen('fortranexport.mat','w')
    if (mp.eq.0) then
     write(6,*) 'Can''t open ''matdemo.mat'' for writing.'
     stop
    end if
!
C     Create variables.
!
    status = matPutVariable(mp,'Numeric',ar1)
    if (status.ne.0) then
     write(6,*) 'matPutVariable ''Numeric'' failed'
     stop
    end if
```

etc etc

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which command are you executing when you get that error? Please show as much details as you have (command, full output, etc.). We can't say what you are doing wrong, because we don't know yet what you are actually doing.

Comment: These guys https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/140510 show how to link with MATLAB libraries. And you will find much more by googling `Undefined reference matopen`.